# Context based Java Bean Validation messages for one property

Tags: java, bean-validation

Let's say I have a simple DTOs like this:

```
public class IdHolder {

    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    // ...
}

public class Transport {

    @Valid @NotNull(message = "{messages.fromLocationRequired}")
    private IdHolder fromLocation;

    @Valid @NotNull(message = "{messages.toLocationRequired}")
    private IdHolder toLocation;

    // ...
}
```

I get nice messages for the following conditions:

- fromLocation=null results in "you must enter your senders location"
- toLocation=null results in "you must enter your receivers location"

but I would also want to get those messages if the objects are not null but their corresponding id is null.

So is there any elegant way in Java Bean Validation to configure the following conditions:

- fromLocation.id=null results in "you must enter your senders location"
- toLocation.id=null results in "you must enter your receivers location"

?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to this in Bean Validation nor Hibernate Validator. A constraint validator (per default) does not have any context information about about the current path.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be solved using the following trick

```
public class IdHolder {

    @NotNull(message = "{messages.group1}", groups=Group1.Info)
    @NotNull(message = "{messages.group2}", groups=Group2.Info)
    private Long id;

    // ...
}

public class Transport {

    @Valid
    @ConvertGroup(from= Default.class , to = Group1.class)
    private IdHolder fromLocation;

    @Valid
    @ConvertGroup(from= Default.class , to = Group2.class)
    private IdHolder toLocation;

    // ...
}
```

And adding GroupSequence if there are confict in the messages.

If you are using Spring, it seems the @validated does somehow the same, job, but I haven't tried.

Best
Emmanuel